# Remove focus ring & border from Django forms using TailwindCSS

Tags: python, django, tailwind-css

**Goal:** No border or focus ring in Django form.

**Current:** I can currently only change certain attributes like text color & rounded corners but not border or focus. I am using [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks) to assign class attributes to the form. I am using [django-tailwindcss](https://github.com/timonweb/django-tailwind) to use tailwind in Django.

**Attempted:** I am using the tailwind `ring-0` & `border-0` tailwind attributes but they are not functioning at all.

**Code:**

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form action="{% url 'marketing:subscribe' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.email|add_class:"bg-black rounded-lg border-0 ring-0 focus:ring-0" }}
    <button class="text-green-300" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

try adding the class "focus:outline-none". Works with buttons at least

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tailwind component in your code then this works

> className="focus:ring-0 focus:ring-offset-0"

Answer (score 0):

To remove border use outline-none in tailwind.

This how i did it

```
class Meta:
    widgets = {
        'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'bob@example.com',
            'class': 'p-6 border-none',
            }),
    }
```